# log4j in a multithread environment. One Appender per Thread or one Logger per Thread or...?

Tags: java, log4j

In a multithreaded environment (web service provider) I need to create log entries in a database per request (normally per thread). What is the approach to use for something like this?

- Same logger for all threads and create an appender per thread. Then at the end of the request/thread close/remove the appender.
- A logger per thread (different class name per thread). At the end of the request/thread somehow release the specific logger
- Other?

Comment: All logging frameworks are thread-safe. If you write the code ignoring the multithreading concern, you'll write correct code.

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

From an [Apache log4j FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7):

> Yes, log4j is thread-safe. Log4j components are designed to be used in heavily multithreaded systems.

As Marko Topolnik comments, just ignore multithreading when planning your logging statements, and let log4j take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the question is not about writing thread-safe code. Is about how to create/gather separate log entries per web service request. In a web service each request is handled by a new thread. You can think about it as create a separate log file for each request. What is the best way to handle this...